# How much milk do I need to make 100 g Paneer?

Tags: milk, cheese-making, paneer

How much full cream milk do I need to make 100 g Paneer (Cottage cheese) at home?

Comment: Paneer and Cottage cheese are different types of cheese.

Comment: You can calculate by using the percentage of fat in the cream and adding just a bit more.

Comment: @doug read the first statement here--http://www.khanapakana.com/recipe/5f64e7c8-d096-4eab-869c-fb9788692de8/cottage-cheese-paneer.

Comment: Well England must have a different opinion to the US. Here paneer is a semi hard cheese as depicted in the image on the site you just linked to. However cottage cheese looks more like this -> http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cottage_cheese . I'm also sure the Indians will be quite offended by people branding lovely paneer cheese to horrible tasteless cottage cheese.

Comment: @jbarker2160 I doubt that the OP knows the percentage of fat in his cheese

Comment: @rumtscho, I said the percentage of fat in the cream... it says right on the carton.

Comment: @jbarker2160 you can then explain your idea in an answer. I cannot imagine a calculation which doesn't require you to know the percentage of fat in the final product. If you have one, it will be helpful for the readers.

Comment: I think the OP is referring not to cream, but to whole milk i.e. whole fat milk. @Doug Paneer is very similar to farmer's cheese and other so-called dry curd cottage cheeses, I believe that it what the OP's linked recipe is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is assuming 3.5% butter fat for the whole milk(UK regulations).

Paneer is between 25% and 27% butter fat.

Since the ratio of fat in milk is mass(or weight depending on the country) per unit volume we can quickly calculate that it would take between 715 and 775 mL of whole milk (assuming all milk fat is captured in the curd) to yield the 25 to 27g of fat that we need for true paneer.

This calculation is even better than a rough recipe because you can gather your curds and press out the liquid until you reach your magic 100g number, ensuring that you have made real paneer and not some other farmers cheese (such as Tvorog which has a higher moisture content or Branza\Brynza which has less before brining.)

Answer (score 1):

A half liter (500 g) of Amul gold milk gives 100 g of paneer. This paneer is very soft and fresh and can be used directly for consuming, and can also be added to vegetables to enhance the taste.

Homemade paneer or cottage cheese is best for children and this is economical too. 1/2 L of Amul gold comes in 28 rs, while 100 g of paneer comes in 39 rs.

So, if one has to take this daily as per their diet, I would recommend that homemade is best.